# How can I simplify this logic expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm working on the expression C and stuck in step 4. I think that we need to group the r and !r but can't figure out how to do that to simplify this expression. Sorry I don't know how to type the whole thing here so I took a picture instead.

[image]

Comment: You made a mistake going from the first line to the second: $q\implies r$ needs to go to $\neg q\lor r,$ not $\neg p\lor r$.

Comment: Thank you I got it